# Is Kullback-Leibler Divergennce not equal to Relative Entropy?

Tags: convex-optimization, machine-learning, information-theory

In many books, Kullback-Leibler Divergence is equal to  Relative Entropy.
$$ 
D_{kl}(u,v) = \sum_{i=1}^n(u_ilog(u_i/v_i).
$$
However,  I find in the book, Convex Optimization (Stephen Boyd) page 90, the KL Divergence is defined as,
$$
 D_{kl}(u,v) = \sum_{i=1}^n(u_ilog(u_i/v_i)-u_i+v_i).
$$
Why KL Divergence has these two different definition? Which one is correct?

Comment: The book (also written by Vandenberghe) clearly mentions "Note that the relative entropy and the Kullback-Leibler divergence are the same when u and v are probability vectors, i.e., satisfy 1Tu = 1Tv = 1.)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're equivalent because $\sum_i u_i=\sum_i v_i=1$.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: equivalent only for probability vectors, as the book mentions